# Convert ts-object with POSIXct to zoo-object

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, posixct

Short code in R

```
aaaa<-ts(rnorm(5), start = as.POSIXct("2022-04-05 04:28:59",tz="UTC"), freq = 1/60)
index(aaaa)
```

result is (this is number of seconds from "1970-01-01". It's correct)

```
[1] 1649132939 1649132999 1649133059 1649133119 1649133179
```

Now I convert this ts-object aaaa to zoo object

```
as.zoo(aaaa)
```

result is

```
1649132880(1) 1649132940(1) 1649133000(1) 1649133060(1) 1649133120(1) 
...
```

Why timecode is changed? In ts object 1649132939, but in zoo 1649132880

Comment: I tried to use as.zooreg. Absolutely the same result.

Comment: OK. Try `zoo(aaaa, time(aaaa))` .  Note that ts objects are not normally used with POSIXct because they can't have POSIXct times.  If possible go directly to zoo without using ts as an intermediate.

Comment: Thank you! That's work. And zooreg(aaaa,start=tsp(aaaa)[1]) too :-) Very strange language

Comment: This is a bug in as.zoo.ts related to the tolerance level it uses but what is strange is trying to use POSIXct with ts and that really is not a good idea.  Note that the zooreg command in your comment sets the frequency to 1 which may not be what you want. Also start(aaaa) can be used to get the start value. I will contact the package maintainer about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Fixed in `zoo` version 1.8-10, already available from [R-Forge](https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=18) and soon from [CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=zoo).

**Details:** `as.zoo()` calls `zooreg()` internally which tries to create a regular time grid in multiples of `1/frequency`. Specifically, this checks whether the time index is sufficiently close to integer multiples of `1/frequency`. Here, this amounts

```
R> all.equal(1649132939 * 1/60, round(1649132939 * 1/60))
[1] TRUE
```

Hence, `zooreg()` decided that an integer number of minutes since the epoch is intended and rounds it to 27,485,548.00 minutes which corresponds to the following number of seconds:

```
R> floor(1649132939 * 1/60) * 60
[1] 1649132880
```

Clearly, this is not intended here. The reason is that the number of seconds is so large that the conventional tolerance in `all.equal()` is not strict enough.

**Fix:** Now `all.equal(..., tolerance = ts.eps^2)` is used where `ts.eps` is a tolerance that is already used for determining whether one of `frequency` or `deltat` is an integer. The new default is strict enough for your application.

```
x <- ts((1:5)^2, start = as.POSIXct("2022-04-05 04:28:59", tz = "UTC"), freq = 1/60)
z <- as.zoo(x)
z
## 1649132939(1) 1649132999(1) 1649133059(1) 1649133119(1) 1649133179(1) 
##             1             4             9            16            25
```

And if it is not strict enough `ts.eps = ...` can be set to an even stricter tolerance.